# Use HttpClientFactory from .NET 4.6.2

Tags: .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I have a .NET 4.6.2 console application (using Simple Injector). I need to make calls to an HTTP service. Having run into issues using HttpClient directly, I'm trying to use HttpClientFactory ( https://github.com/aspnet/HttpClientFactory ) instead.

The project/library is .NET Standard 2.0 so it should?? work in .NET 4.6.2, but it uses stuff like IServiceCollection, which is in Core only.

So my question is can I use HttpClientFactory in a non-Core application.

Comment: `IServiceCollection` is also not core only.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.iservicecollection?view=aspnetcore-2.1 says ASP.NET Core 2.1, 2.0, 1.1, 1.0

Comment: Look at the Nuget package and you will see https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/2.1.1

Answer (score 58, accepted):

All of the Microsoft.Extensions.* packages target .NET Standard 2.0. That means that you can use Dependency Injection, Configuration, Logging *and* HttpClientFactory if you add the appropriate package to your application.

You need to add [Microsoft.Extensions.Http](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/) to use HttpClientFactory and [Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly/) if you want to use it with [Polly](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Polly/)

To configure HttpClientFactory you'll have to add [Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/) to your "main" project. Microsoft.Extensions.Http package only depends on [Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions/) which contains the interfaces, not the DI provider itself.

Comment: Some of my web service projects are already using Ninject as DI provider. Is it possible to use the HttpClientFactory in this scenario as well? Is there any other mechanism for using HttpClientFactory  with Ninject?

PS: My web services are not in .NET core but using .NET 4.7.*

Comment: Is there any sample code in terms of the configuration?

Comment: @Vinod we do the same thing, we use a `new ServiceCollection` and use all the extensions methods on that to bind all the things, then have a `INinjectHttpClientFactory` that uses the `IServiceCollection` service provider to actually build things.

Comment: Is it possible to do it inside Ninject module?

Answer (score 37):

As @Panagiotis Kanavos said, you need to add 
**Microsoft.Extensions.Http** and **Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection**. 
Here is my ConsoleApp code, you can refer to it.

```cs
class Program
{
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         Test();
         Console.Read();
     }

     static async void Test()
     {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        //services.AddSingleton<xx,xx>();
        //...
        services.AddHttpClient();
        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        
        var httpClientFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>();
        var client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        var response = await client.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://www.baidu.com"));
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(content);
     }
}
```

Comment: If I loop the Test(), will it created multiple instances of client?

Comment: @Gopi yes, but if you register serviceProvider outstide off this method then every  `var client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();` will return the same client

Comment: HttpClient can be created multiple times it does not matter. HttpMessageHandler will be reused, as long as you use the same instance of the factory, which is the important part here.