# Use HttpClientFactory in .NET 4.7.1 Webapi

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, httpclient, httpclientfactory

I have a WebAPI 2 app under .NET Fw 4.7 that needs to be converted from singleton `HttpClient` implementation to `HttpClientFactory`.

I'm trying to use the [Microsoft.Extensions.Http](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/) library, but I am running into issues on how to actually use it. I followed a couple of examples, but most of them refer to .NET Core, which is not an option at this time.

The closest example I was able to find is [Use HttpClientFactory from .NET 4.6.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51498896/use-httpclientfactory-from-net-4-6-2), but that doesn't give a full example either.

I think a lot of issues I'm having are because of my relative ignorance of DI, and how to properly use it in WebAPI space.

Going with the code from the above link:

```cs
var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection().AddHttpClient().BuildServiceProvider();
var httpClientFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>();
var client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
```

How do I implement this so I can access `CreateClient()` in a controller (or other classes) properly?

Comment: Can you share with us please one of your Controller's relevant part to see what does *ignorance of DI* mean?

Comment: please try to use this repo as this can be used as same way https://github.com/uhaciogullari/HttpClientFactoryLite