# HttpClient - Single Instance across the app or static instance at controller level

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, .net-4.6

In our .NET API, we were creating the `HttpClient` instances in each controller action. As the application should have a single instance of `HttpClient` for each HTTP endpoint it consumes.

We have got a couple of options.

- Create a base controller class with `public readonly static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient()` and inherit all the
  controllers from this.
- Each controller should have it's own `private readonly static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient()`
  declaration.

I am not sure if this will impact the performance (when thousands of users hit the application). Can anyone guide me to follow the right approach, please?

Comment: Either 1) Use `HttpClientFactory`, which manages the lifetimes of the handlers appropriately, or 2) Use .NET Core 2.1+, in which case the lifetime issues of `HttpClient` more-or-less go away, and you can just use normal instances. There are other advantages to using `HttpClientFactory` in ASP.NET applications

Comment: Compulsory reading: https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: ... but note that the issues described there were fixed in SocketsHttpHandler, which became the default handler in .NET Core 2.1

Comment: OP specified .net-4.6

Comment: Sure, just worth noting that the issues there were fixed 3 years ago

Comment: Our application is based on .net-4.6.

Comment: There is an approach specified for the .Net 4.6.2 in this post. Shall we follow the same  for our application if we want to use the `HttpClientFactory` https://stackoverflow.com/a/51499006/641103

Comment: @AJQarshi Yes indeed that's the preferred way. The `AddHttpClient` [registers](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpClientFactory/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/DependencyInjection/HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L37) the `DefaultHttpClientFactory` for `IHttpClientFactory`. Then you can retrieve that from the DI container.