# Should I pass the full URL or just the domain to ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint()?

Tags: c#, http, dotnet-httpclient, .net-4.7.2

I've been reading about how to use `HttpClient` in .NET Framework.

The two main points I gathered was that `HttpClient` should be a singleton, and `ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint()` needs to be called in case of DNS changes.

But what do you pass to `FindServicePoint()`?

In this [example](http://byterot.blogspot.com/2016/07/singleton-httpclient-dns.html), it passes the full URL:

```
var sp = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(new Uri("http://foo.bar/baz/123?a=ab"));
sp.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 60*1000; // 1 minute
```

However, in this [example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1194406/Using-HttpClient-As-It-Was-Intended-Because-You-re), it only passes in the base URL:

```
Uri baseUri = new Uri("https://someresource.com");
...
ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(baseUri).ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 60 * 1000;
```

The `HttpClient` instance will be making requests to different resources all from the same host (eg. `domain.com/resourceA` and `domain.com/resourceB`).

I've read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51499006/2063755), however unfortunately I can't use it as we don't have DI set up in our project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't matter since only host (and port if not default) portion of url will be used. It makes sense, because `ServicePoint` manages connections, and only host and port are needed to define a connection to remote server. Documentation of [ServicePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepoint?view=net-7.0) says:

> The ServicePoint class handles connections to an Internet resource
> based on the host information passed in the resource's Uniform
> Resource Identifier (URI). The initial connection to the resource
> determines the information that the ServicePoint object maintains,
> which is then shared by all subsequent requests to that resource.

If not convinced by the description, you can ensure that in [source code](https://source.dot.net/#System.Net.ServicePoint/System/Net/ServicePointManager.cs,199):

```
private static string MakeQueryString(Uri address) => address.IsDefaultPort ?
    address.Scheme + "://" + address.DnsSafeHost :
    address.Scheme + "://" + address.DnsSafeHost + ":" + address.Port.ToString();
```

This is how lookup key for service point object is created when you call `FindServicePoint` method (only host and port are used).

So whether you pass "http://somehost.com" or "http://somehost.com/somepath?somequery=x" - result will be the same.

Comment: Thanks for showing the source code, that really does prove your point.